# Cascade update of nodes in tree

Tags: neo4j

I have a graph as acyclic tree with undefined depth. I need to count number of descendants for each node including node itself. So the final result should be something like that:

```
9
|\
4 4
|\ \
2 1 3
|   |\
1   1 1
```

So for each node this number would be sum of numbers of its descendants + 1.
How can it be done in one query?
I could come up with something like that:

```
MATCH (n)
SET n.count = SIZE((n)<-[:PARENT*0..]-());
```

But it means a subquery for each node. Having over 1 300 000 nodes it takes ages.
Better way would be to set "1" for each leaf and ascend to the root calculating each node. Is it possible to do in one query?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for

```
MATCH (start)<-[:PARENT*0..]-(n)
RETURN id(start), count(n) as numberOfChildren
```

which counts how many nodes are found on the path. But I don't know how it performs on really large graphs (my test graph has only ~100s nodes).

Comment: I need actually to set node's property in order to be able to use it later and not count it every time. Also on 1 300 000 nodes it runs hours

Answer (score 0):

You could already optimize your query by limiting the number of paths you are processing, e.g. like this :

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE EXISTS((n)<-[:PARENT]-())
MATCH path=(n)<-[:PARENT*0..]-(m) 
WHERE NOT EXISTS((m)<-[:PARENT]-())
UNWIND nodes(path) AS node
WITH n, COUNT(DISTINCT node) AS count
SET n.count = count
```